# Загрузка 32-х битной библиотеки

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Всем привет! Решил написать простенький лаунчер для игры от нечего делать. Полазил в разных сорцах и начал с того, что подключаю нативную либо приложения (беру из пакета):

```
PackageInfo info1;
    ApplicationInfo info;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {

            info1 = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.ketchapp.dunkshot", 0);
            info = info1.applicationInfo;
            System.load(info.nativeLibraryDir + "/libMyGame.so");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

После запуска получаю кекс:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.ketchapp.dunkshot-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

Я тестировал этот код на 2-х устройствах:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (Android 4.2.2) - старое устройство
- Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X (MIUI 9, Android 7) - новое устройство

В итоге получается так: на Самсунг все работает отлично, либо подгружается, а вот на Xiaomi не хочет.
Есть какие-нибудь идеи по решению проблемы.
P.s. пробовал на другой игре - Minecraft PE. Итог - аналогично
P.s.s. Для Minecraft PE уже есть лаунчер - BlockLauncher. Но прикол в том, что там идентичный код. Однако он работает на моих 2-х устройствах, а мой код - нет)

Comment: Дай угадаю: внутри BlockLauncher бинарники для обоих платформ?

Comment: BlockLauncher берет либы и пакета - /data/..../com.mojang.minecraftpe/lib/..

Comment: Гораздо интереснее, сколько штук их там вообще

Comment: Где именно - в майнкрафте или в блок лаунчере?

Comment: Очевидно же: там, откуда пытаемся грузить библиотеки

Comment: В пакете майнкрафта - библиотеки armeabi-v7a и больше ничего..